# Python3.5: Import Error - Module already exists

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hello I am trying to send an API request to `http` via Python's `requests` package and getting an ImportError while using `import requests` for python 3.5.2.

I tried to install requests package via `pip3.5 install requests` that says

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from requests)
```

if I list the install packages `pip3.5 list` I got

```
appdirs (1.4.3)
bencode (1.0)
better-bencode (0.2.1)
certifi (2017.7.27.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12.2)
gevent (1.2.2)
greenlet (0.4.12)
humanfriendly (4.4)
idna (2.5)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
magneticod (0.6.0)
magneticow (0.6.0)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
Naked (0.1.31)
parse-torrent-name (1.1.1)
pip (9.0.1)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.18.3)            <--- Here its already installed
setuptools (33.1.1)
urllib3 (1.22)
uvloop (0.8.0)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
```

this is how I am running the python script `python3 script.py` (interpreting with python3.5)

your help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your `script.py` and the full error message?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have multiple deployments of 3.5? You could try printing out the `base_prefix` for `python3`, e.g. `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)` or `sys.path`

Comment: @NelsonYeung It has just one line `import requests`

Comment: @AChampion I got /usr/local

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling `requests`? Side note: this is why working with `virtualenv` is a big plus as your works starts to grow

Comment: @AChampion you are right I had multiple deployments of 3.5 and they were somehow conflicting with each other. So, I removed everything related to python 3.x and reinstalled 3.5.2 and everything works now. +1